# How would i make AIM/MSN connectivity in the PHP

Tags: php, msn, aim

How do I make robot connect AIM/MSN and stay connected, and respond to a message with a PHP function ?

I can't seem to find even an AIM function that would work or isn't from 2001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think AIM/MSN uses XMPP. Check out the PHP [libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) for XMPP.

Comment: @jmoon, I looked it up to see just how bad it is. It looks sorta like HTTP... if HTTP got screwed up. used cryptic encodings at every chance, and used nothing but capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement [OSCAR](http://iserverd.khstu.ru/oscar/) with sockets.

There is a tutorial to socket programming:  http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

**Edit:**  I stumbled across this resource that may help you:  http://wip.asminog.com/workshop/webicqpro/webicqpro.html